# Facing this error while installing oracle to write sql based python code in both CMD prompt and also in Pycharm

Tags: python, cx-oracle

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iHxz.png)

Facing this error while installing oracle to write sql based python code in both CMD prompt and also in Pycharm.

Please give answers

tried to install cx-Oracle in cmd prompt and Pycharm. But facing issue in building wheel
Building wheel for cx-Oracle (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

Answer (score 1):

cx_Oracle has been superseded by python-oracledb so prebuilt binaries for newer Python versions are only available with python-oracledb! Take a look at the [upgrade notes](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html#appendix-c-the-python-oracledb-and-cx-oracle-drivers). Depending on your requirements you can make use of the new thin mode which doesn't require Oracle Client libraries to be installed.

Comment: See the [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) release announcement.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to following URL https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and download the build tools.
Restart the terminal and proceed with executing the command again.